Are there events associated with the Temple (beside Earthquake and Darkness) that occurred because of the Crucifixion of Christ?
We are aware from the recordings in the Gospels of the Christians that phenomena such as an Earthquake shook (Matthew 27:51), and that there was darkness (Matthew 27:45). And other posted question have dealt with these in relation to Secular or Extra-biblical confirmations.
But were there other happenings that could be considered the result of the crucifying of Jesus, that are also recorded in extra-biblical documents and ancient writings?  Especially events related to Jewish ritual or Temple worship?

Jesus warned in advance about an event as a direct consequence of his crucifixion and resurrection. This was included in the one sign he told his followers to look out for prior to the immediate destruction of the Temple, which turned out to be in A.D. 70. Before the Temple would become desolate, something would happen that would be the sign for them to flee to the mountains.

"When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of
by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let
him understand): Then let them which be in Judaea flee to the
mountains." Matthew 24:15-16 K.J.V.

This, Jesus said, would be seen to happen just at the start of an awful period of great tribulation.
The literal kingdom of Israel was to end following the encirclement of a besetting army, at the hands of an Abominator. This would lead to the destruction of the Temple itself. The holy land around Jerusalem would first be trampled (e.g. Mount Moriah, whereas the Valley of Hinnom was totally unholy) and desolation begin. Note that desolation is not the same as desecration, which does not destroy. It profanes. But the desolation that comes with invading armies often involves the tearing down of items held to be sacred by those they are attacking, such as the Temple.
Whereas many think 'the Holy Place' that Jesus said would see an abomination standing in it must mean the Temple, that does not automatically follow. Consider how, if Jesus had meant the Temple, would any but the priests and those in the Temple at the time of the abomination appearing see it? Thousands of Jews would not see anything being 'set up' inside the Temple by an Abominator: most of them would be dead or in chains by then. But before then they would see Jerusalem having an embankment set up all around the city's outer walls. And Rome was the Abomination that trampled the Holy Land and set up the fortifications that enabled them to tear down the city walls and gates. It was the Roman army that stood all around the city, attacking it to desolate it.
Many appeal to Daniel's prophecy (as Jesus included it). In Daniel 8:13 an angel speaks of a rebellion that causes desolation, the sanctuary being given up, (or over to desolation) and trampling underfoot of 'the Beautiful Land' (vs. 9). The vision concerned the distant future, so was to be sealed up (vs. 26). There seems to be a general opinion that there were abominable things carried out in and around Jerusalem by Antiochus IV Epiphanes. On 25 Kislev 168 B.C. he desecrated the Lord's altar. This may be why the later prophecy of Jesus, which alluded to this, is taken to mean there had to be some abomination carried out in A.D. 70, inside the Temple, very shortly before it was utterly destroyed.
On the other hand, there is nothing amiss with viewing the warning sign Jesus gave as to meaning the advancing of the Roman troops; an abomination in itself, trampling the Beautiful Land, to desolate it. For sure, Jesus' followers had to see something as a sign that would enable them to flee instantly. If the sign was something that happened once the city walls had been breached and the Temple was filled with Roman troops, it would be too late for everybody still inside Jerusalem.
The answer offered is that the flooding in over the land, by Roman armies, was the sign that the time of terrible tribulation was starting, which would end in A.D. 70, the Temple being torn down.  Josephus, the Jewish historian who was there, describes the atrocities in language very close to Jesus' descriptions. It was the end of the days - of an era - where Temple worship and sacrifices were stopped once and for all; a far more lasting blow than in Daniel's vision. And the events that culminated in A.D. 70 were the direct result of Jesus having been crucified, nearly 40 years earlier, as he said. Had they heeded him, they would not have cried for his blood to be upon them and their children; they would have asked for Barrabus to be crucified instead. See Matthew 23:34-38.

Yes, Other Events!Indeed, there were other "mysterious" events that occurred that coincide with the monumental Crucifixion of Christ! And these are recorded in Jewish literature, outside the Bible. [Note that the New Testament is also Jewish literature. But we refer to extra-biblical documents here.]
1. During the Jewish holy day of Yom Kippur, the High Priest picked two lots out of a bowl for the purpose of randomly designating which sacrificial goat would be "for the Lord" and which would be the Scapegoat (for Azazel).
It was considered a "good omen" if the lot marked "for the LORD" was picked up by the priest's right hand. BUT for forty years up to the Destruction of the Temple, the lot appeared in the left hand! (Yoma 39a)
This harbinger of bad luck began the year Christ was crucified!
2. A crimson sash was tied to the horns of the Scapegoat (Azazel) before it was led into the wilderness to die for the sins of the nation of Israel.
Part of the crimson sash was cut off and tied to the door of the Temple. When the goat died in the desert miraculously the red sash turned to white, signaling that God had accepted their sacrifice and forgiven their sins!
For forty years before the Destruction of the Temple in 70 C.E. the sash stopped turning white! (See Mishna)
3. According to the Jewish Mishna, enormous oil lamps 50 cubits high were erected in the Temple. These lit up nearly every courtyard in Jerusalem (Sukkah 5:3)
But interestingly, something happened approximately 40 years before the Temple was destroyed in 70 C.E. The westernmost Lamp would not burn! (Scholars believe this light was used to ignite the other lights.) The once brightly lit Temple was now shrouded in darkness (Talmud, Yoma 39)
4. Again, something else occurred causing much alarm.  Usually the Temple doors were opened to let in only certain priests in special Holy Days. In fact, only the High Priest, on the Day of Atonement (Yom Kippur) even dared to venture into the "Holy of Holies" inner sanctum!
BUT at approximately 30 C.E. (A.D.), the usually secure closed Temple doors would open by themselves! (Zechariah 11:1; Yoma 39)
5. Also, a little more than forty years before the Destruction of the Temple in 70 A.D. the power of pronouncing Capital Punishment was taken away from the people of Israel. The scepter is taken from Judah, and the Messiah has not come, was the lamentation of the rabbis! (Talmud, Sanhedrin).
This presented a dilemma, for the Messiah had to come before the scepter was removed---and the Scripture cannot be broken! (Genesis 49:10)
Mysterious CauseWhat could possibly be the mysterious cause of all of these events?...these bad omens?
All these foreboding happenings couldn't possibly be laid to mere coincidence. Random chance is inadequate to explain these troublesome occurrences that led up to the Destruction of the Great Temple in the year 70.
What went wrong in 30 C.E. that caused the holy ritual to be rejected, as was recorded in Jewish rabbinical literature? The other Jewish literature (the Gospels of the New Testament) mentioned an earthquake, and a darkness over the land at the time of the Crucifixion, which many saw as a sign of disapproval of God concerning this deed. Are all these tied together?
[Note: the Sanhedrin moved away from meeting in the Temple, at this time, as well. Many blame this move on structural damage caused by the geological phenomena.]

Are there events associated with the Temple (beside Earthquake and Darkness) that occurred because of the Crucifixion of Christ?
The short answer is yes, but not all are going to believe them. There are sources from the Apocrypha and even some Catholic Mystics that give us details about the events surrounding the Crucifixion of Jesus.
Here is what Blessed Catherine Emmerich wrote down in her revelations about the ”Apparitions on Occasion of the Death of Jesus”:

Among the dead who rose from their graves, and who were certainly a hundred in number, at Jerusalem, there were no relations, of Jesus. I saw in various parts of the Holy Land others of the dead appear and bear testimony to the Divinity of Jesus. Thus I saw Sadoch, a most pious man, who had given all his property to the poor and to the Temple, appear to many persons in the neighbourhood of Hebron. This Sadoch had lived a century before Jesus, and was the founder of a community of Essenians: he had ardently sighed for the coming of the Messias, and had had several revelations upon the subject. I saw some others of the dead appear to the hidden disciples of our Lord, and give them different warnings.
Terror and desolation reigned even in the most distant parts of Palestine, and it was not in Jerusalem only that frightful prodigies took place. At Thirza, the towers of the prison in which the captive's delivered by Jesus had been confined fell down. In Galileo, where Jesus had travelled so much, I saw many buildings, and in particular the houses of those Pharisees who had been the foremost in persecuting our Saviour, and who were then all at the festival, shaken to the ground, crushing their wives and children. Numerous accidents happened in the neighbourhood of the Lake of Genazareth. Many buildings fell down at Capharnaum; and the wall of rocks which was in front of the beautiful garden of the centurion Zorobabel cracked across. The lake overflowed into the valley, and its waters descended as far as Capharnaum, which was a mile and a half distant. Peter's house, and the dwelling of the Blessed Virgin in front of the town, remained standing. The lake was strongly convulsed; its shores crumbled in several places, and its shape was very much altered, and became more like what it is at the present day. Great changes took place, particularly at the south-eastern extremity, near Tarichea, because in this part there was a long causeway made of stones, between the lake and a sort of marsh, which gave a constant direction to the course of the Jordan when it left the lake. The whole of this causeway was destroyed by the earthquake. Many accidents happened on the eastern side of the lake, on the spot where the swine belonging to the inhabitants of Gergesa cast themselves in, and also at Gergesa, Gerasa, and in the entire district of Chorazin. The mountain where the second multiplication of the loaves took place was shaken, and the stone upon which the miracle had been worked split in two. In Decapolis, whole towns crumbled to the earth; and in Asia, in several localities, the earthquake was severely felt, particularly to the cast and north-east of Paneas. In Upper Galilee, many Pharisees found their houses in ruins when they returned from keeping the feast. A number of them, while yet at Jerusalem, received the news of what had happened, and it was on that account that the enemies of Jesus made such very slight efforts against the Christian community at Pentecost.
A part of the Temple of Garizim crumbled down. An idol stood there above a fountain, in a small temple, the roof of which fell into the fountain with the idol. Half of the synagogue of Nazareth, out of which Jesus had been driven, fell down, as well as that part of the mountain from which his enemies had endeavoured to precipitate him. The bed of the Jordan was much changed by all these shocks, and its course altered in many places. At Macherus, and at the other towns belonging to Herod, everything remained quiet, for that country was out of the sphere of repentance and of threats, like those men who did not fall to the ground in the Garden of Olives, and, consequently, did not rise again.
In many other parts where there were evil spirits, I saw the latter disappear in large bodies amid the falling mountains and buildings. The earthquakes reminded me of the convulsions of the possessed, when the enemy feels that he must take to flight. At Gergesa, a part of the mountain from which the devils had cast themselves with the swine into a marsh, fell into this same marsh; and I then saw a band of evil spirits cast themselves into the abyss, like a dark cloud.
It was at Nice [present day France], unless I am mistaken, that I saw a singular occurrence, of which I have only an imperfect remembrance. There was a port there with many vessels in it; and near this port stood a house with a high tower, in which I saw a pagan whose office was to watch these vessels. He had often to ascend this tower, and see what was going on at sea. Having heard a great noise over the vessels in the port, he hurriedly ascended the tower to discover what was taking place, and he saw several dark figures hovering over the port, and who exclaimed to him in plaintive accents: If thou desirest to preserve the vessels, cause them to be sailed out of this port, for we must return to the abyss: the great Pan is dead.' They told him several other things; laid injunctions upon him to make known what they were then telling him upon his return from a certain voyage which he was soon to make, and to give a good reception to the messengers who would come to announce the doctrine of him who had just died. The evil spirits were forced in this manner by the power of God to inform this good man of their defeat, and announce it to the world. He had the vessels put in safety, and then an awful storm arose: the devils cast themselves howling into the sea, and half the city fell down. His house remained standing. Soon afterwards he went on a great journey, and announced the death of the great Pan, if that is the name by which our Saviour had been called. Later he came to Rome, where much amazement was caused by what he related. His name was something like Thamus or Thramus. - Chapter LVI. Apparitions on Occasion of the Death of Jesus.

Here are a few details Catherine Emmerich noted about the earthquake and the apparition of the dead in Jerusalem. The Temple and the Jewish priests are seen in great detail here:

The earthquake which produced the deep chasm at Calvary did much damage in different parts of Palestine, but its effects were even more fatal in Jerusalem Its inhabitants were just beginning to be a little reassured by the return of light, when their terror was reawakened with double force by the shocks of the earthquake, and the terrible noise and confusion caused by the downfall of houses and walls on all sides, which panic was still farther increased by the sudden appearance of dead persons, confronting the trembling miscreants who were flying to hide themselves, and addressing them in the most severe and reproachful language.
The High Priests had recommenced the sacrifice of the Paschal lamb (which had been stopped by the unexpected darkness), and they were triumphing at the return of light, when suddenly the ground beneath them trembled, the neighbouring buildings fell down, and the veil of the Temple was rent in two from the top to the bottom. Excess of terror at first rendered those on the outside speechless, but after a time they burst forth into cries and lamentations. The confusion in the interior of the Temple was not, however, as great as would naturally have been expected, because the strictest order and decorum were always enforced there, particularly with regard to the regulations to be followed by those who entered to make their sacrifice, and those who left after having offered it. The crowd was great, but the ceremonies were so solemnly carried out by the priests, that they totally engrossed the minds of the assistants. First came the immolation of the lamb, then the sprinkling of its blood, accompanied by the chanting of canticles and the sounding of trumpets. The priests were endeavouring to continue the sacrifices, when suddenly an unexpected and most appalling pause ensued; terror and astonishment were depicted on each countenance; all was thrown into confusion; not a sound was heard; the sacrifices ceased; there was a general rush to the gates of the Temple; every one endeavoured to fly as quickly as possible. And well might they fly, well might they fear and tremble; for in the midst of the multitude there suddenly appeared persons who had been dead and buried for many years! These persons looked at them sternly, and reproved them most severely for the crime they had committed that day, in bringing about the death of the just man,' and calling down his blood upon their heads. Even in the midst of this confusion, some attempts were, however, made by the priests to preserve order; they prevented those who were in the inner part of the Temple from rushing forward, pushing their way through the crowds who were in advance of them, and descending the steps which led out of the Temple: they even continued the sacrifices in some parts, and endeavoured to calm the fears of the people.
The appearance of the Temple at this moment can only be described by comparing it to an ant-hill on which persons have thrown stones, or which has been disturbed by a stick being driven into its centre. The ants in those parts on which the stones have fallen, or which the stick has disturbed, are filled with confusion and terror; they run to and fro and do nothing; while the ants in those parts which have not been disturbed continue to labour quietly, and even begin to repair the damaged parts.
The High Priest Caiphas and his retinue did not lose their presence of mind, and by the outward tranquillity which their diabolical hardness of heart enabled them to preserve, they calmed the confusion in a great degree, and then did their utmost to prevent the people from looking upon these stupendous events as testimonies of the innocence of Jesus. The Roman garrison belonging to the fortress of Antonia likewise made great efforts to maintain order; consequently, the disturbance of the festival was not followed by an insurrection, although every heart was fixed with fear and anxiety, which anxiety the Pharisees endeavoured (and in some instances with success) to calm.
I remember a few other striking incidents: in the first place, the two columns which were placed at the entrance of their Holy of Holies, and to which a magnificent curtain was appended, were shaken to the very foundations; the column on the left side fell down in a southerly, and that on the right side in a northerly direction, thus rending the veil in two from the top to the bottom with a fearful sound, and exposing the Holy of Holies uncovered to the public gaze. A large stone was loosened and fell from the wall at the entrance of the sanctuary, near where the aged Simeon used to kneel, and the arch was broken. The ground was heaved up, and many other columns were thrown down in other parts of the Temple.
An apparition of the High Priest Zacharias, who was slain between the porch and the altar, was seen in the sanctuary. He uttered fearful menaces, spoke of the death of the second Zacharias, [14] and of that of St. John Baptist, as also of the violent deaths of the other prophets. The two sons of the High Priest Simon, surnamed the Just (ancestors of the aged Simeon who prophesied when Jesus was presented in the Temple), made their appearance in the part usually occupied by the doctors, of the law; they also spoke in terrific terms of the deaths of the prophets, of the sacrifice of the old law which was now about to cease, and they exhorted all present to be converted, and to embrace the doctrines which had been preached by him whom they had crucified. The prophet Jeremiah likewise appeared; he stood near the altar, and proclaimed, in a menacing tone, that the ancient sacrifice was at an end, and that a new one had commenced. As these apparitions took place in parts where none but priests were allowed to enter, Caiphas and a few others were alone cognisant of them, and they endeavoured, as far as possible, either to deny their reality, or to conceal them. These prodigies were followed by others still more extraordinary. The doors of the sanctuary flew open of themselves, and a voice was heard to utter these words: Let us leave this place;' and I saw all the angels of the Lord instantly leave the Temple. The thirty-two Pharisees who went to Calvary a short time before our Lord expired were almost all converted at the foot of the Cross. They returned to the Temple in the midst of the confusion, and were perfectly thunderstruck at all which had taken place there. They spoke most sternly, both to Annas and to Caiphas, and left the Temple. Annas had always been the most bitter of the enemies of Jesus, and had headed every proceeding against him; but the supernatural events which had taken place had so completely unnerved him that he knew not where to hide himself. Caiphas was, in reality, excessively alarmed, and filled with anxiety, but his pride was so great that. he concealed his feelings as far as possible, and endeavoured to reassure Annas. He succeeded for a time; but the sudden appearance of a person who had been dead many years marred the effect of his words, and Annas became again a prey to the most fearful terror and remorse.
Whilst these things wore going on in the Temple, the confusion and panic were not less in Jerusalem. Dead persons were walking about, and many walls and buildings had been shaken by the earthquake, and parts of them fallen down. The superstition of Pilate rendered him even more accessible to fear; he was perfectly paralysed and speechless with terror; his palace was shaken to the very foundation, and the earth quaked beneath his feet. He ran wildly from room to room, and the dead constantly stood before him, reproaching him with the unjust sentence he had passed upon Jesus. He thought that they were the gods of the Galil?an, and took refuge in an inner room, where he offered incense, and made vows to his idols to invoke their assistance in his distress. Herod was equally alarmed; but he shut himself up in his palace, out of the sight of every one.
More than a hundred persons who had died at different epochs re?ntered the bodies they had occupied when on earth, made their appearance in different parts of Jerusalem, and filled the inhabitants with inexpressible consternation. Those souls which had been released by Jesus from Limbo uncovered their faces and wandered to and fro in the streets, and although their bodies were, the same as those which they had animated when on earth, yet these bodies did not appear to touch the ground as they walked. They entered the houses of their descendants, proclaimed the innocence of Jesus, and reproved those who had taken part in his death most severely. I saw them passing through the principal streets; they were generally in couples, and appeared to me to glide through the air without moving their feet. The countenances of some were pale; others of a yellow tint; their beards were long, and their voices sounded strange and sepulchral. Their grave-clothes were such as it was customary to use at the period of their decease. When they reached the place where sentence of death was proclaimed on Jesus before the procession started for Calvary they paused for a moment, and exclaimed in a loud voice: Glory be to Jesus for ever and ever, and destruction to his enemies!' Towards four o'clock all the dead returned to their graves. The sacrifices in the Temple had been so interrupted, and the confusion caused by the different prodigies was so great that very few persons ate the Paschal lamb on that evening. - The Earthquake. - Apparitions of the Dead in Jerusalem.

At the crucifixion, all the disciples fled, with the exception of one. According to tradition, who was the one disciple who stayed with Christ to what, at that time, appeared to be the very end!
As Jesus was crucified, did his apostles stay in Jerusalem (rather than flee to Galilee)? We may never know for sure. According to reports, just before Jesus was arrested in Jerusalem and crucified there, he told his 12 apostles that they will scatter like sheep. Sure enough, as Jesus is arrested, Mk writes, “And they all left Him and fled.” When the apostles “fled”, did they in fact all flee, and flee all the way back to Galilee? It seems unlikely.
“This suggestion seems intrinsically improbable and against the evidence” (P. Gardener-Smith [Biblical Scholar]).
One Apocryphal document, (unfortunately I can not recall which one) have the Apostles, except the Apostle St. John, fleeing and hiding amongst various tombs, at the moment Christ was arrested, knowing that the Jews would not search these areas for them. Their fear of the Jewish authorities was that great!
